# Site page associated with list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sitepages

We are using SP to host our company's SOPs/How-to-guides. I am trying find the best way to achieve the following:

1. Have a home page listing all SOPs in a nice design where the list is searchable by
   title and also by metadata/tags
2. When clicking on an item, navigating to a separate page for that SOP which is an HTML
   page that can contain anything (text/image/video)
3. Make this process as simple as possible as various people will be able to create SOPs

The best I have come up with is to create a list which contains each SOP and when an item is created in the list, use automation to create an associate site page from a template (and hopefully pre-fill the title from the list item name).

This approach feels fragile (have to handle edits and deletes of list items) and as I am pretty new to Sharepoint it would be great to get some experienced views on other ways to tackle this problem.

Thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a communication site (modern experience). Use a combination of hero web parts, highlighted content web parts (filter and return the pages you want listed on the home pages using metadata). Users can use the top search bar to search for specific content.

You can add columns to the site pages library, which can then be used by editors from the page details pane when creating their page.

If you can [create modern page templates](https://support.microsoft.com/office/page-templates-in-sharepoint-faa92408-0c84-4e3d-8460-3c28065e7873), which can then be selecting from the new page pane.